# Error When Running Servlet The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willi

Tags: java, servlets

```
enter code here
// Servlet Name 
@WebServlet("/InsertData")
```

Error Is

> Description ::::The origin server did not find a current
>   representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose
>   that one exists.

Comment: Html Code<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Insert Data</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <!-- Give Servlet reference to the form as an instances  
    GET and POST services can be according to the problem statement-->
    <form action="./InsertData" method="post"> 
        <p>ID:</p>  
        <!-- Create an element with mandatory name attribute, 
        so that data can be transfer to the servlet using getParameter() -->
        <input type="text" name="id"/> 
        <br/> 
        <p>String:</p>

Comment: @WebServlet("/InsertData") 
public class InsertData extends HttpServlet { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
  
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,  
HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

Comment: Add your code to your question not in the comments

Comment: lund he trewewvr rreveebdfgvdd